# Extract numbers with EXPONENTS from heterogeneous text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to take out some unformatted numerical data from text file. In the textfile, the numbers are somewhere separated by single space and somewhere by multiple spaces, somewhere by tabs; pretty heterogeneous text :(
  I want Python to ignore all spaces/tabs and identify whole numerical values and put them in an array/list. Is it possible to do this using Python?

EDIT: There are many numbers written in scientific/exponential notation e.g. `1.2345E+06`, and Python does not recognize them as numbers. So `\d` does not work simply :(

I don't want to use a normal string search for this purpose (given there are many strings/words which are of no interest/use). The [regular expression module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) documentation has nothing mentioned about this issue.

Comment: Please show us a sample of the text file, and the effort you made so far. Where in your code are you having problems?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Extract numbers from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

If lines are like "    2.3e4  " or "2.6" or so, try:

```
^\s*?([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?(e[+-]?\d+)?)\s*$
```

notice the \s*? mark (non-greedy zero/more spaces). Dont forget the question mark there - not including the question mark will make you capture only the last digit of your number due to greediness.

**AFAIK** python has not a special symbol, other than \d for digits, to capture numbers

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression like `\s+([-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)\s+` (adapted from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)). Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989198/python-find-regexp-in-a-file) to see how you can search for a regular expression in a file.

Comment: Is there any regular expression special character (similar to \d )for matching numbers in scientific/exponential formats e.g `1.23450E+06` ?